# How to handle dynamic images within a FittedBox

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am currently implementing a dropdown button as the title of a scaffold.

In this dropdown, some of the options do not have a relevant image and therefore just text is shown. I have it working great, my only problem is, an error is always thrown when the app runs (not hot reloaded) because the Image doesn't load instantaneously meaning that FittedBox is trying to fit an empty widget, once it loads it is fine, and then hot reloads work fine with no errors too because the image is already loaded. Here is my code for my DropDownMenuItems:

```
return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: company.id.toString(),
                    child: Center(
                        child: FittedBox(
                            child: Center(
                                child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: (config.companyLogos[company.id] != null)
                              ? FittedBox(
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    config.companyLogosPath +
                                        config.companyLogos[company.id],
                                    height: 50,
                                  ),
                                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                )
                              : FittedBox(
                                  child: Text(
                                  company.name,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )))));
```

And here is the error that is thrown when the app runs, I am sure this is due to what I described above:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 313 pos 12: 'width > 0.0': is not
flutter: true.
```

Considered solutions:

A possible solution would be to supply the width of image, I could include this in my companyLogos map by making it a Map of Maps and including the filename and the width in the sub map.

However, I've trie this and it doesn't seem to work, it just makes my images a lot smaller than if I used an unset width.

I am not explicitly defining width to make it keep its aspect ratio whilst still fitting in the row.

I'm probably missing a trick here on how to handle images in flutter/dart, any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: i cannot imagine any point of combining `FittedBox` with `Image` widget, the other case is with `Text` - here `FittedBox` is very handy

Comment: @pskink As these images are dynamic and could be any size, I need FittedBox to make sure that it fits within the dropdownmenuitem, can you propose an alternative? It would be much appreciated

Comment: *"As these images are dynamic and could be any size"* - it does not matter - it is `Image` responsibility to `fit:` them

Comment: @pskink Thank you I wasn't aware Image had this functionality, thank you !

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink I have solved the issue.

I solved it by scrapping the FittedBox completely and using Image's 'fit:' property.

Here is my fixed code:

```
return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: company.id.toString(),
                    child: Center(
                        child: FittedBox(
                            child: Center(
                                child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: (config.companyLogos[company.id] != null)
                              ? Container(
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                  config.companyLogosPath +
                                      config.companyLogos[company.id],
                                  height: 50,
                                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                ))
                              : FittedBox(
                                  child: Text(
                                  company.name,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )))));
```